# PayPal button with drop down menu not working

Tags: dropdown, paypal

I'm trying to add a paypal button to my wordpress site but when I add the code I get an error. I've tried looking up solutions and everything says to remove the extra  tags which I don't have in my code. Anyone run into this issue before?

```
    <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" />
    <input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="D8VH5555GHLP6" />
    <table><tbody><tr><td>
    <input name="on0" type="hidden" value="" />"A" 2.5'x6' Banners</td>
</tr><tr><td><select name="os0"><option value="">"A" $500.00 USD</option>
    <option value="">"A"x2 $750.00 USD</option>
    <option value="">"A"x3 $1,000.00 USD</option>
    </select></td></tr></tbody></table>
    <input name="currency_code" type="hidden" value="USD" />
<input alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" type="image" />
<img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put tl:dr:

1. Use simple text for your **Item** and **Menu Option Names**.
2. Don't edit or remove `values`.
3. Add the `"`'s to your descriptive text inside the `<option>` tags.

---

Don't use `"`'s in your **Menu Option Name** fields when creating the button.

> [image]

It is critical that the `value`'s not be changed from those generated by PayPal. When you edit your code copied from the [paypal button creator](https://www.paypal.com/bm/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_button-designer&factory_type=buynow), retain the value `attributes` of your `<input>`'s and `<options>`.

```
<table><tbody>
<tr><td>
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="A 2.5'x6' Banners">"A" 2.5'x6' Banners
</td></tr>
<tr><td><select name="os0">
    <option value="A">"A" $500.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Ax2">"A"x2 $750.00 USD</option>
    <option value="Ax3">"A"x3 $1,000.00 USD</option>
</select></td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

In this working form, I added `"` in the text between opening and closing `<option>` tags - this is the text the user sees. If the values were empty or different from those generated by PayPal I got the following error:

> PayPal cannot process this transaction because of a problem with the
>   seller's website. Please contact the seller directly to resolve this
>   problem.